# Spanish Language translation problems containing double quotes

Tags: android, android-resources

I have A string in my es-String.xml in one of the Android projects

```
En el futuro, se recordarán sus detalles siempre que active la opción "Mantenerme conectado"
```

which is always displayed without quotes

I know i can use '\' character to forcefully display double quotes (") but why doesn't Android support double quotes inside Spanish Strings just like English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the double quotes in String use \" for this please replace your String with this, It's working for me.

```
 <string name="str_name">En el futuro, se recordarán sus detalles siempre que active la opción "\"Mantenerme conectado\""</string>
```